# Let $g_n= {2^2}^n +1 $. Prove $g_0 · g_1 · · · g_{n−1} = g_{n} − 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> Let $g_n= {2^2}^n +1 $. Prove $g_0 · g_1 · · · g_{n−1} = g_{n} − 2$.

I'm not sure how to start this proof, if it should be done algebraically or if I should try to use a proof by induction.

Comment: Is what you've written correct? $g_0g_1g_2 = (3)(5)(17) \neq g_1 = 5$

Comment: it's a typo, it should read $g_n -2$ on the right hand side.

Comment: I corrected the statement; it seems overwhelmingly likely that this is meant.

Comment: by the way, this identity implies in particular that each of the $g_n$ (all of them odd numbers) is relatively prime to the previous ones, thus each pair of $g_i$ and $g_j$ ($i \neq j$) are prime to each other. This implies  that there are infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 2):

Induction is the way to go. Having established the base case, assume $g_0\cdots g_{n-1}=g_n-2$. Then,
$$g_0\cdots g_{n-1}g_n=(g_n-2)g_n=g_n^2-2g_n$$
Now, expand the righthand side and see what you get.

Comment: Induction works fine, but I still find this identity mysterious.